# T4CConnection.doDescribeTable() call for every insert statement?

Tags: java, oracle, performance, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

During looking into the performance in my app, I noticed that for each object creation via JPA, framework calls `T4CConnection.prepareStatement` method in the Oracle JDBC driver (ojdbc8 19.3.0.0), code is constantly getting the table description via `T4CConnection.doDescribeTable()`, even if all inserts are for the same table. The retrieval of the table description takes around 20% longer then real insert statement execution. Can it be somehow tuned? Do you know what is the purpose to call table description every time for each insert, shouldn't it be cached for systems that schema does not change frequently?

Unfortunately it is hard to extract the code sample as it at framework level. 
Stack is JPA, Hikari, OJDBC.
In general JPA saveAll method calls following:

- com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement
- com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate

PrepareStatement from Hikari internally calls a driver classes, where in my case it is: oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement()
Couldn't find the exact source code, but main concept is same as here https://github.com/mikesmithjr/ora-jdbc-source/blob/master/OracleJDBC/src/oracle/jdbc/driver/PhysicalConnection.java

Simplified code:

```java
public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql, String[] columnNames) throws SQLException {
        (...) //check if insert statment
        AutoKeyInfo info = new AutoKeyInfo(sql, columnNames);

        doDescribeTable(info); <-- table describe occurs here, pretty slow

        OraclePreparedStatement pstmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) prepareStatement(newSql); <-- in prepareStatement i can benefot from the cache

        return pstmt;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share a minimal example that demonstrates it?

Comment: Without in-depth knowledge of the internal workings of the Oracle JDBC driver, it is probably not possible to really answer this. However, at a guess, the driver doesn't know if your database changed since the last time it prepared the statement, so it will need to describe it again. In any case, using something that caches prepared statements should help.

Comment: problem description updated with driver code sample